# In WSO2 ESB, How to Get Error Message from validate mediator

Tags: validation, wso2, esb, mediator, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB, How to Get Error Message from validate mediator if schema on-fail sequence called.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

define fault sequence for your proxy and where read ERROR_MESSAGE/Error codes..You can find sample in the default fault sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using expression $ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE